# Gifs shown inside a label doesn't update itself regulary in Pyqt5

Tags: python-3.x, animated-gif, pyqt5, qthread

I have a loading widget that consists of two labels, one is the status label and the other one is the label that the animated gif will be shown in. If I call `show()` method before heavy stuff gets processed, the gif at the loading widget doesn't update itself at all. There's nothing wrong with the gif btw(looping problems etc.). The main code(caller) looks like this:

```
self.loadingwidget = LoadingWidgetForm()
self.setCentralWidget(self.loadingwidget)
self.loadingwidget.show()
...
...
heavy stuff
...
...
self.loadingwidget.hide()
```

The widget class:

```
class LoadingWidgetForm(QWidget, LoadingWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        pince_directory = SysUtils.get_current_script_directory()  # returns current working directory
        self.movie = QMovie(pince_directory + "/media/loading_widget_gondola.gif", QByteArray())
        self.label_Animated.setMovie(self.movie)
        self.movie.setScaledSize(QSize(50, 50))
        self.movie.setCacheMode(QMovie.CacheAll)
        self.movie.setSpeed(100)
        self.movie.start()
        self.not_finished=True
        self.update_thread = Thread(target=self.update_widget)
        self.update_thread.daemon = True

    def showEvent(self, QShowEvent):
        QApplication.processEvents()
        self.update_thread.start()

    def hideEvent(self, QHideEvent):
        self.not_finished = False

    def update_widget(self):
        while self.not_finished:
            QApplication.processEvents()
```

As you see I tried to create a seperate thread to avoid workload but it didn't make any difference. Then I tried my luck with the QThread class by overriding the `run()` method but it also didn't work. But executing `QApplication.processEvents()` method inside of the heavy stuff works well. I also think I shouldn't be using seperate threads, I feel like there should be a more elegant way to do this. The widget looks like this btw:

[image: gondola] Processing...
Full version of the gif:[image: gondola]

Thanks in advance! Have a good day.

Edit: I can't move the heavy stuff to a different thread due to bugs in pexpect. Pexpect's spawn() method requires spawned object and any operations related with the spawned object to be in the same thread. I don't want to change the working flow of the whole program

Answer (score 0):

In order to update GUI animations, the main Qt loop (located in the main GUI thread) has to be running and processing events. The Qt event loop can only process a single event at a time, however because handling these events typically takes a very short time control is returned rapidly to the loop. This allows the GUI updates (repaints, including animation etc.) to appear smooth.

A common example is having a button to initiate loading of a file. The button press creates an event which is handled, and passed off to your code (either via events directly, or via signals). Now the main thread is in your long-running code, and the event loop is stalled — and will stay stalled until the long-running job (e.g. file load) is complete.

You're correct that you can solve this with threads, but you've gone about it backwards. You want to put your long-running code in a thread (not your call to processEvents). In fact, calling (or interacting with) the GUI from another thread is a recipe for a crash.

The simplest way to work with threads is to use `QRunner` and `QThreadPool`. This allows for multiple execution threads. The following wall of code gives you a custom `Worker` class that makes it simple to handle this. I normally put this in a file `threads.py` to keep it out of the way:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QRunnable


class WorkerSignals(QObject):
    '''
    Defines the signals available from a running worker thread.
    error
        `tuple` (exctype, value, traceback.format_exc() )

    result
        `dict` data returned from processing
    '''
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    error = pyqtSignal(tuple)
    result = pyqtSignal(dict)


class Worker(QRunnable):
    '''
    Worker thread

    Inherits from QRunnable to handler worker thread setup, signals and wrap-up.

    :param callback: The function callback to run on this worker thread. Supplied args and 
                     kwargs will be passed through to the runner.
    :type callback: function
    :param args: Arguments to pass to the callback function
    :param kwargs: Keywords to pass to the callback function

    '''

    def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        # Store constructor arguments (re-used for processing)
        self.fn = fn
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.signals = WorkerSignals()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        '''
        Initialise the runner function with passed args, kwargs.
        '''

        # Retrieve args/kwargs here; and fire processing using them
        try:
            result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
            exctype, value = sys.exc_info()[:2]
            self.signals.error.emit((exctype, value, traceback.format_exc()))
        else:
            self.signals.result.emit(result)  # Return the result of the processing
        finally:
            self.signals.finished.emit()  # Done
```

To use the above, you need a `QThreadPool` to handle the threads. You only need to create this once, for example during application initialisation.

```
threadpool = QThreadPool()
```

Now, create a worker by passing in the Python function to execute:

```
from .threads import Worker # our custom worker Class
worker = Worker(fn=<Python function>) # create a Worker object
```

Now attach signals to get back the result, or be notified of an error:

```
worker.signals.error.connect(<Python function error handler>)
worker.signals.result.connect(<Python function result handler>)
```

Then, to execute this `Worker`, you can just pass it to the `QThreadPool`.

```
threadpool.start(worker)
```

Everything will take care of itself, with the result of the work returned to the connected signal... and the main GUI loop will be free to do it's thing!

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and answering me with an in-depth answer. But as I understood, you are creating a thread separated from the main thread. I've already stated that I can't move the heavy work to another thread due to bugs in pexpect(at the end of my post)